# Google Analytic not work only on particular domain

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I have some wierd issue what is new for me and I'm realy confused. Google Analytic I use many time (a lot) and on one site GA don't want to work via JS.

It is a standard script:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

At first I thought that another JavaScript or jQuery block analysis code. I traded places scripts from head to body parts. Nothing influences. In real time I can only see my own actions, but I can not see from other visitors. If I use [SSGA PHP class](https://github.com/dancameron/server-side-google-analytics) I can see all visits but Avg. Session Duration is arround 00:00:02 and 00:00:09 what is realy problematic and bonce rate is to hight ~ 70% - 90%. PHP SSGA class don't track duration for some reason.

Note: This website have arround 2000 visitors each minut.

I need or JavaScript solution what work or some PHP API what work fine.

Thanks.